# how to use iron-meteor along with default routing of meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, webrtc, iron-router, recordrtc

When I create a new meteor application, it already has a "/" route. I have added my webpage on this route.
Now, I need to add a new route "/something", so for this I used iron-router package. But then it requires he default route to be routed from iron-router which requires me to make lot of changes in my existing code.
Is there a way to just use iron-router for specific routes and keep the default routes as it it?

Answer (score 0):

Your router.js:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate:'mainLayoutTemplateName',
    loadingTemplate: 'loadingTemplateName'
});

Router.route('/', function() {
    this.render('homeTemplateName');
});

Router.route('/anotherRoute', function() {
    this.render('anotherTemplateName');
});
```

**Edit:**

You also need to have {{> yield}} in your main layout template which tells iron-router where to render templates in routes.

For example:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{> navigation}}

    <div class="content-area">
        {{> yield}}
    </div>
</template>

<template name="navigation">
    This will always be visible in every route according to the template above.
</template>
```